# Tortoise SVN branch must be ancestrally related to trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The problem appeared when merging the branch code to the trunk

What should be done to actually avoid the problem ?

Comment: The trite answer is to merge a branch that is ancestrally related to the trunk. The reality is that the SVN handling of common ancestors is poor and so you can still choose to merge with a 'from' and 'to' revision and then it won't care about where the common ancestry is (or is not)

Comment: @Paul - could you just answer the question ? Which type of merge are you referring to ? Is it completely valid ?

Comment: Unfortunately vague questions get vague answers. What will work every time is a "2-URL merge". If you are using the command line then type "svn help merge" and it will explain the process. If you are using Tortoise then you need to choose "merge two different trees" to see this option.

Answer (score 1):

From the documenation as discussed in my comment:

```
 This form is called a '2-URL merge':

 svn merge SOURCE1[@REV1] SOURCE2[@REV2] [TARGET_WCPATH]

 You should use this merge variant only if the other variants do not
 apply to your situation, as this variant can be quite complex to
 master.

 Two source URLs are specified, identifying two trees on the same
 branch or on different branches. The trees are compared and the
 difference from SOURCE1@REV1 to SOURCE2@REV2 is applied to the
 working copy of the target branch at TARGET_WCPATH. The target
 branch may be the same as one or both sources, or different again.
 The three branches involved can be completely unrelated.

 TARGET_WCPATH is a working copy path; if omitted, '.' is generally
 assumed. The special cases noted above in the 'complete' merge form
 also apply here.

 SOURCE1 and/or SOURCE2 can also be specified as a working copy path,
 in which case the merge source URL is derived from the working copy.
```